# Generic factory function with bounds doesn't always check existing constructors

Tags: typescript

I am beginning with typescript (3.0.3). I have the following hierarchy (simplified example from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
class Animal {}

class Bee extends Animal {}

class Lion extends Animal {
  constructor(name: string) {
    super();
  }
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new(n: string) => A): A {
  return new c("some name");
}

console.log(createInstance(Lion));
console.log(createInstance(Bee)); // why no error?

new Bee("blah"); // error
```

I would expect the `createInstance` function to only work for `Animal` subclasses that additionally have a constructor that takes a `string`, but the code works and the `Bee` instance is created just fine. The next line that calls the `Bee` constructor directly doesn't work, as expected.

Could anybody please explain what is wrong with my assumptions? And how the `createInstance` function manages to call a constructor with incorrect parameters?

The following does work as expected (class hierarchy unchanged):

```
function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new() => A): A {
  return new c();
}

console.log(createInstance(Lion)); // Argument of type 'typeof Lion' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Lion'.
console.log(createInstance(Bee));
```

The compiler reports an error that an instance of `Lion` cannot be created as it doesn't have a constructor with no arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the signature of `Bee` is compatible with the signature of the parameter `new(n: string) => A`. If you call the parameter and the actual implementation requires fewer parameters, the extra parameter is just ignored by the implementation and no harm will occur.

In the second example, the parameter signature has no arguments, so none will be passed in, but if the implementation we send in requires a parameter it will not get it, so runtime errors can occur.

This is in general the way [function compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) works in Typescript, the signatures don't have to be identical, but the assignment should be safe.

**Edit**

We can use some conditional types to ensure if the constructor has too few arguments we get an error

```
class Animal {}

class Bee extends Animal {}

class Lion extends Animal {
constructor(name: string) {
    super();
}
}

type ErrorIfFewer<T, TError = "Too few arguments"> = T extends new (n: infer U) => Animal ? U extends string ? {} : TError : TError
function createInstance<Ctor extends new(n: string) => Animal>(c: Ctor & ErrorIfFewer<Ctor>) : InstanceType<Ctor> {
    return new c("some name") as InstanceType<Ctor>;
}

console.log(createInstance(Lion));
console.log(createInstance(Bee)); // Type 'typeof Bee' is not assignable to type '"Too few arguments"'.
```

I would not use this unless you have a very good reason for it. The way typescript works should be fine in most cases, and the restriction might surprize others.

Comment: This is very surprising, but I haven't read the page you mention yet. For example:

    function a() {}

    function b(s: number) {}

    a()
    b(1)

    a(1) // Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
    b() // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

does not ignore too many arguments.

Comment: @wujek true, on direct invocation you get an error if you pass more arguments. But this works `function a() { }
let b: (n: string) => void = a; 
b("")`

Comment: Oh snap, that's a bummer. Thanks for your answer, I will read the page to hopefully learn why they did it.

Comment: @wujek If you want to force the compiler into an error, there is black magic we can employ to do so. But if you don't have a very good reason for it I would just go with the default behavior

Comment: I'm starting to learn ts so I don't really know if I want it or not :D But coming from a strongly and statically typed platforms I would at least like to know how to turn the black magic on. Could you tell me?

Comment: @wujek added it